# How to removing telephone and email from newlfm letter?

Tags: letters, newlfm

I am trying to remove Telephone and Email from the address in [a `newlfm` template in WriteLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/1898974vrkncp#/4774646/).

I commented them in this way:

```
%\PhrPhone{Phone} % Customize the "Telephone" text
%\PhrEmail{Email} % Customize the "E-mail" text
```

And:

```
%\phonefrom{(000) 111-1111} % Phone number

%\emailfrom{john@smith.com} % Email address
```

But, still it appears, however empty. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phone number and email are added by the following lines:

```
\newlfmP{addrfromphone} % Print a phone number under the sender's address
\newlfmP{addrfromemail} % Print an email address under the sender's address
```

Thus you have to remove or comment these lines.